# Missing i2c-1 through i2c-5 in my redpitaya

Tags: linux, i2c, redpitaya

I downloaded i2c-tools from [this](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/i2c-tools-3.1.2.tar.gz/) link:

Then i ran the following commands:

```
tar xvzf i2c-tools-3.1.2.tar.gz
cd i2c-tools-3.1.2
make
sudo make install
```

I got [these](http://prntscr.com/eqdvr8) warnings. When I go to my /dev/ I don't see i2c-1. I don't know what's causing [this](http://prntscr.com/eqdwmg). Not sure what I'm missing. I know for RPi I had to change some configurations in the device tree but I don't recall doing the same for red pitaya. [Here](http://prntscr.com/eqdz7x)'s the result of `uname -a`

Comment: Do you have the appropriate kernel modules loaded?  You would need at least `i2c-dev` and a lower level `i2c` driver.

Comment: I did a `sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure my OS is the latest version. How do i check if I have the right modules? i don't have `/lib/modules` @larsks

Comment: I'm not familiar with red pitaya.  Normally, a missing `/lib/modules` would be a sign of something wrong, but not if your system relies on a static kernel configuration.  Probably you will find better answers if there is a forum or mailing list for red pitaya.